# Python Special Characters Encoding

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a python script that reads a **CSV** file and writes in a **XML** file. I have been hitting a wall trying to find out how to read special characters such as: ç, á, é, í, etc. The script runs perfectly fine without special characters. That is the script header:

```
# coding=utf-8

'''
@modified by: Julierme Pinheiro
'''
import os
import sys
import unittest
from unittest import skip
import csv
import uuid
import xml
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
import owslib
from owslib.iso import *
import pyproj
from decimal import *
import logging
```

The way I retrieve information from the csv file is shown bellow:

```
# add the title
                title = data[1]
                titleElement = identificationInfo[0].getElementsByTagName('gmd:title')[0]
                titleNode = record.createTextNode(title)
                titleElement.childNodes[1].appendChild(titleNode)
                print "Title:" + title
```

Note: If data[1], second column in the csv file, contains a special character as found in "Navega**çã**o" the script fails (**It does not write anything in the xml file**).

The way a new XML file is created based on a blank Template XML is shown bellow:

```
 # write out the gemini record
                filename = '../output/%s.xml' % fileId
                with open(filename,'w') as test_xml:
                    test_xml.write(record.toprettyxml(newl="", encoding="utf-8"))
            except:
                e = sys.exc_info()[1]
                logging.debug("Import failed for entry %s" % data[0])
                logging.debug("Specific error: %s" % e)

    @skip('')
    def testOWSMetadataImport(self):
        raw_data = []
        with open('../input/metadata_cartapapel.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
            for columns in reader:
                raw_data.append(columns)   

        md = MD_Metadata(etree.parse('gemini-template.xml'))
        md.identification.topiccategory = ['farming','environment']
        print md.identification.topiccategory
        outfile = open('mdtest.xml','w')
        # crap, can't update the model and write back out - this is badly needed!!
        outfile.write(md.xml) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Could someone help to solve this issue, please?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: There are [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples) in the Python 2 CSV docs that show how to handle Unicode data. BTW, you should open CSV files in binary mode, but I guess you are on Linux, so you don't really need to bother about that unless you want to be able to run your script on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

That's unicode. csv can't read unicode if you are in python 2.7. In python 3.x you can pass the utf-8 option while opening the file.

In python you can decode the data[1] to utf-8 like below.

```
title = data[1].decode('utf-8')
```

Some of the windows legacy windows components in english might require the 'cp1252'. If the above decoding fails, try this.

```
title = data[1].decode('cp1252')
```

Comment: Dear @VinayakKolagi, you went right to the target. I am running python 2.7.1 and I just read about your solution in : (http://www.tulane.edu/~howard/CompCultES/unicode.html)

Comment: Hi @VinayakKolagi, I inserted " import codecs" in the script header and I am running python 2.7.1 and I am unable to decode variables. I got the following error for .decode('utf-8'): Traceback (most recent call last): File "(stdin)", line 1, (in module) File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf-8.py", line 16, in decode return codec.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Looks like the encoding was not in utf-8. Try the cp1252 decoding which I have added in the answer.

Comment: Hi @VinayakKolagi. That was it. Right to target: ('cp1252'). Whoever is facing this problem running python 2.7.1, may try this solution. My problem is gone.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting the answer.